# How can i connect laptop webcam RJ E85792 CK 77 94v-0 wire to usb cable

Tags: digital-logic

Camera wire colours

1. Unshield
2. Green
3. Yellow
4. Orange
5. Red
6. White
7. Brown
8. Unshield

[image]

Comment: identify the parts, then identify which wire connect where on which part.

Comment: https://www.instructables.com/id/Updated-Laptop-Webcam-to-USB-Cable/

Comment: I can't comment, but just wanted to mention that Dan's answer is correct, and the resulting wired webcam works in Linux just fine. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvwqP.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvwqP.png) Here's the dmesg output: [900880.675105] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd [900880.961901] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=13d3, idProduct=5711 [900880.961906] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2 [900880.961908] usb 3-4: Product: USB 2.0 UVC VGA WebCam [900880.961910] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: Azure

Comment: I used the following black cable (GND)
red and brown cable (DATA)
orange cable (VCC)
I connected them and Windows 10 recognized the cam immediately.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on a webcam salvaged from an eeepc, model e85792 ck77 94v-0, very similar to yours, only the wiring colors were different. Here is a picture: 
[image]

I couldn't make it work but here is a semi-answer, so maybe you can. Please note that I have very little knowledge of electronics.

I couldn't find any datasheet for this webcam so I tried on my own with a multimeter. In my case, there were, from left to right (bottom to top on your image):

- a single black cable (GND)
- a red and a brown cable, intertwined (DATA +/-)
- a single orange cable (VCC)
- 4 other cables which I assume are for the microphone

As you can see [here](https://www.instructables.com/id/Salvaging-and-Reusing-an-Old-Laptop-Camera-to-USB-/), you will need 2 1N4001 Diodes, but I had none so I used 1N4007, in the same design as on the link. I had the exact same result by connecting directly (without diodes) the GND and VCC to a 3.3V power supply.

I connected those cables to the USB, on which red is VCC and black is GND, and tried both wirings for DATA cables.

This worked, as my computer showed a "USB2.0 webcam is plugged in" notice message (instant nerdgasm).

Unfortunately, as soon as I launched the "Camera" Windows 10 application, the webcam just rebooted indefinitely, with a LED flashing along with a USB plug-unplug sound each time.

If you are still trying, I'd be glad to hear your feedback.

Comment: Isn't the diods just to limit the voltage? As far as I can see the webcams in laptops run at 3.3 volt. 2 x diods is about 2 volt drop.